# Function of undocumented pads on PCB mount power module

Tags: pcb-design, footprint

I'm hoping someone may be able to explain to me why are there extra pads on the bottom of APXW003 DC/DC SMPS PCB mount module from ProLynx series from GE Industrial. I am doing a design and it turns out cheaper for me to use these modules than to make a SMPS from discrete parts.

The datasheet, which can be found here:

http://apps.geindustrial.com/publibrary/checkout/APXW003A0X?TNR=Data%20Sheets|APXW003A0X|generic

makes no mention of the circular pads which can be seen in the land pattern presented on page 19 of the document. I have ordered a few of these modules and checked for continuity of these pads, and found it to be as in the picture attached (two of them connect to GND, one of them connects to VIN). I have read the datasheet twice carefully and was not able to find any mention of these except on page 19 where they are just labelled "keepout".

Could someone explain to me the function of these pads? Should I connect them to GND and VIN on the PCB as I have found (with a multimeter) they are internally connected to those pads? They strike me as very strange as solder can easily bridge a pad and those circular "keepout" marks - especially the one between "VS+" and "VOUT". What is their function?

Thank you! 
-Igor
[image: Land Pattern Connections]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is they are pogo-pin-test-bench test points.

I'd be amazed if one of the "GND" ones isn't in some way Vout or related to it.

They use those to test the module in an automated jig to see if it works as intended, BUT...

You cannot use them reliably, because you have no knowledge of what they are connected to exactly. One may be connected to GND directly, or it may have a buffer component like a 1Ohm resistor for some unknowable reason.

I think it's a bit sloppy to put them so close to actual pads and not even mention a DNC notice on a few more pages, but, companies these days get to be a little sloppy some times.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I believe that must be right. It is just odd to me that "GND" test pad is put so close and in between Vout and Vs+ - I can see solder paste creating shorts there...

Comment: @IgorEE yeah, that's what makes me feel it's a bit of a sloppy design. If your PCB needs high-flow paste for other more complex power components you might be in trouble (since I try not to swear here). They could have at least made that one and the Vin one 40 mil or smaller. It's not that hard to place something on a bed of pins with enough accuracy for even 20mil if you're a large company with 10000's of production.

Answer (score 2):

If they are labelled "keepout" then the correct thing to do is keep out. Preferably avoid tracks under these areas, otherwise at least guarantee solder mask is present.

Even if you know they are connected to Vin and Gnd internally, don't connect them. They will have some purpose in testing : those next to Vin and Gnd pads are probably used for Kelvin measurements, to verify the input voltage under load.

They may not be directly connected; there may be ferrite beads or feedthrough capacitors for EMI filtering : in test, they may want to test this filtering is fitted and working correctly, not accidentally bridged by stray solder.

Why there's another "gnd" next to the output? Maybe to test the output reservoir capacitor or another EMC filter.

The big benefit of these modules is that someone has taken care to achieve the EMC limits shown, to simplify your own design. (Any cost saving is a bonus)

So : the best thing to do is follow the instructions and Keep Out. Otherwise, the unit may *appear* to work fine, but it probably won't, and the most likely result is failed EMC tests.